# How to stop a command on only one server discord.py?

Tags: python, datetime, discord, discord.py

So the issue is when I use the stop command on one server it stops on literally every server that has the bot. I believe it may have to do with the fact that I am not storing the tasks anywhere. Maybe it is because it is all controlled by a globalvar? Sorry for the messy code. Here is the code that handles everything:

````
import pytz
import datetime as dt
import discord
import asyncio

from datetime import timedelta
from pytz import timezone
from pytz import common_timezones
from discord.ext import commands

cancelled = 0
Tz = {
    'PST': timezone('America/Los_Angeles'),
    'CEST': timezone('Europe/Berlin'),
    'EST': timezone('America/New_York'),
    'UTC': pytz.utc
}
# UTC = pytz.utc
# CEST = timezone('Europe/Berlin')
# PST = timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
# EST = timezone('America/New_York')
# print(CEST.zone, UTC.zone, PST.zone, EST.zone)


class Countdown(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def countdown(self, ctx, eventname, time1, time2, timespecifier, timezone1):
        h, m = time2.split(':')
        m = int(m)
        h = int(h)

        if timespecifier == 'PM':
            if h == 12:
                h -= 12
            h += 12
            print(h)
        if timespecifier == 'AM':
            if h == 12:
                h -= 12
        month, day, year = time1.split('/')
        month = int(month)
        day = int(day)
        year = int(year)

        # datetimeFormat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        # timezoneend = pytz.timezone(Tz[timezone1])

        date = dt.datetime(year, month, day, h, m,)
        cur_date = dt.datetime.now(Tz[timezone1])
        cur_date.replace(microsecond=0)

        print(cur_date)
        print(date)

        aware_date = date.astimezone(Tz[timezone1])
        aware_date.replace(microsecond=0)

        diff = aware_date-cur_date.replace(microsecond=0)
        print(diff)
        days, hours, minutes, seconds = diff.days, diff.seconds // 3600, diff.seconds % 3600 / 60.0, diff.seconds % 60
        print(seconds)
        time = await ctx.send(f'{eventname} Countdown \nDays left: {int(days)} \nHours left: {int(hours)} \nMinutes left: {int(minutes)} \n Seconds left: {seconds}')
        global cancelled
        cancelled = 0

        while diff.seconds != 0 & cancelled == 0:
            if cancelled == 1:
                break
            if seconds <= 0 and minutes <= 0 and hours <= 0 and days <= 0:
                break
            if days < 0:
                days = 0
                minutes = 0
                hours = 0
                seconds = 0
                await time.edit(content=f'{eventname} Countdown \nDays left: {int(days)} \nHours left: {int(hours)} \nMinutes left: {int(minutes)} \n Seconds left: {seconds}')
                print("Stopping")
                break

            await asyncio.sleep(60)

            cur_date = dt.datetime.now(Tz[timezone1])
            aware_date = date.astimezone(Tz[timezone1])

            diff = aware_date - cur_date.replace(microsecond=0)

            days, hours, minutes, seconds = diff.days, diff.seconds // 3600, diff.seconds % 3600 / 60.0, diff.seconds % 60

            await time.edit(content = f'{eventname} Countdown \nDays left: {int(days)} \nHours left: {int(hours)} \nMinutes left: {int(minutes)} \n Seconds left: {seconds}')

    @commands.command()
    async def stop(self, ctx):
        global cancelled
        cancelled = 1
        await ctx.send("Stopping timer")


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Countdown(client))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a global dictionary that would store all the countdown timers.

```py
timers = {}
```

Now when you call the `countdown` command, you add to this dictionary using the server ID.

```py
@commands.command()
async def countdown(ctx):
    serverID = ctx.guild.id

    if serverID in timers and timers[serverID]:
        await ctx.send('A timer has already begun.')
        return

    timers[serverID] = True

    # Then you add your timer logic
    while timers[serverID]:
        # The timer is running...

    # After coming out of the loop, it would be a good idea to delete it from the dictionary
    del timers[serverID]
```

And then, to stop the timer you simply change `True` to `False`.

```py
@commands.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    serverID = ctx.guild.id

    if serverID not in timers:
        await ctx.send('There is no active countdown in this server.')
        return

    timers[serverID] = False
```

I think this should solve the problem you are facing. If you want a single server to be able to have multiple timers, you'll have to use something more unique than the server ID, the message ID would be a good idea.

**Note:** Since all this data is stored in memory, the moment the bot goes offline everything will be lost. It would be wise to store this data in a file or a database as well and read from it every time the bot starts up.